# Firebase login error in VS code (with React app) because running scripts is disabled

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, visual-studio-code, deployment

I was trying to deploy my react app to with firebase and this happened after puting thhis command in the terminal: firebase login

firebase : File C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on                                    d because running scripts is disabled on
this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.       .microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- firebase init
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException    
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use git bash terminal to solve this issue
2. Using "cd" command navigate to your project directory
3. Instead of "firebase login" use "firebase login --interactive" in the git bash terminal.

Also I found that if you open git bash terminal in vs code you will not have issues navigating the interactive server options.

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode Editor Terminal Select "Git Bash",  refer the screenshot
and enter the run the command there.
[image: In VSCode Editor Terminal Select "Git Bash", please refer the screenshot and enter the run the command there,]